# highcharts heatmap large values

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I have a heatmap example in the folowing [link](http://jsfiddle.net/1fj2o0j7/). The example works perfectly as intended.
The javascript is as follows:

```
$(function () {
$('#chart').highcharts({
        chart: {'zoomType': 'x', 'panKey': 'shift', 'height': 350, 'panning': 'true', 'renderTo': 'chart', 'type': 'heatmap'},
        title: {'text': 'test1'},

        xAxis:{categories: ['0', '39', '43', '53', '594', '2138', '2793', '3163', '3450', '5548', '7338', '8238', '8484', '8768', '9890', '10164', '10805', '11136', '11238', '11246', '11260']
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 280
        },
        yAxis: {'categories': ['Plag. Conf.']},
        series: [{'dataLabels': {'color': '#000000'}, 'data': [[0, 0, 0.22442165397324812], [1, 0, 0.7752904636683974], [2, 0, 0.23883733197735627], [3, 0, 0.3482875869692335], [4, 0, 0.258070694541037], [5, 0, 0.47030915290735903], [6, 0, 0.3483451910956659], [7, 0, 0.4273295797570711], [8, 0, 0.42551220835600195], [9, 0, 0.17503429231614342], [10, 0, 0.400566592735601], [11, 0, 0.7072621636869421], [12, 0, 0.5863121178991313], [13, 0, 0.15765898852599733], [14, 0, 0.31159690000560425], [15, 0, 0.31414482011700673], [16, 0, 0.17269348665931927], [17, 0, 0.33469995479740144], [18, 0, 0.7833757398833074], [19, 0, 0.873319790409567], [20, 0, 0.24485995289730964]], 'name': 'test1', 'borderWidth': 1}],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>Passage starting at ' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> has <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> for <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have another example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sp4mg43t/) containing a large number of values that doesn't work as well as the first fiddle, even though both have been generated using the same program.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In case you have so much bars / cols, how it should be printed ? There is no physically enough space in pixels to print all of them, including borders.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thank you. Should I increase the width then?